# I would like advice on a ubuntu based web page to expose a pdf and a ftp source directory

Tags: pdf

How do i get started. If i could just run evince on one of several pdf's and
have ftp directory with some source a user could download. this is all i want.
Is drupal the way? The pdf has a lot of math in  it and making html out of it would probably not render it correctly. I really think a button to run evince or okular on it is morel likely to get a faithful rendering.

Comment: Use the builtin viewer of the browser?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use an HTML `<object>` of `type='application/pdf'` to render PDFs with the plugin in the web browser.